# If statement inside for loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search a column(in my case column 3) and see if it has the string being passed into the function Extract. When the If statement gets a hit it then copies the text from a different column of the same row (in my case column 6) and exits the `For` loop. The `For` loop in the function is to scan through all rows in column 3. To check for a match I have used the worksheet functions available in VBA.

```
Function Extract(x As String, Y As Integer) As String

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To Y
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(x, Cells(i, 3))) = True Then
            Extract = Cells(i, 6)
            Exit For   
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

I have tried running this piece of code i have written an this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to add "partial match" functionality

- **partial match**

  using the `Find()` method of `Range` object:

  ```
  Function Extract(x As String, Y As Integer) As String    
      Dim f As Range

      Set f = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Y, 3)).Find(what:=x, lookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| "xlPart" value of "lookAt" argument makes the "partial" match functionality
      If Not f Is Nothing Then Extract = f.Offset(,3).Text    
  End Function
  ```

  using `LookUp()` method of `Application` object:

  ```
  Function Extract(x As String, Y As Integer) As String
      Dim f As Variant

      f = Application.VLookup("*" & x & "*", Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Y, 6)), 4, False) '<--| the "False" argument and the asterisks ("*") makes the "partial" match functionality
      If Not IsError(f) Then Extract = f
  End Function
  ```
- **exact match**

  using the `Find()` method of `Range` object:

  ```
  Function Extract(x As String, Y As Integer) As String    
      Dim f As Range

      Set f = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Y, 3)).Find(what:=x, lookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| "xlWhole" value of "lookAt" argument makes the "exact" match functionality
      If Not f Is Nothing Then Extract = f.Offset(,3).Text    
  End Function
  ```

  using `LookUp()` method of `Application` object:

  ```
  Function Extract(x As String, Y As Integer) As String
      Dim f As Variant

      f = Application.VLookup(x, Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Y, 6)), 4, False)'<--| the "False" 4th argument makes the "exact" match functionality
      If Not IsError(f) Then Extract = f
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Match` function, to look for x at Column 3. If there will be a match in column 3 you will get that row number. If not Extract will return a string to let you know that there was no match.

**Note**: In my tests `Extract` wouldn't run in my Excel, maybe it's a saved word or something, so I modified to `Extract2`

**Edit 1**: Modified the code to support the PO's request to find also partial String - added the `*` wildcard before and after `x`.

```
Function Extract2(x As String, Y As Integer) As String

If Not IsError(Application.Match("*" & x & "*", Columns(3), 0)) Then ' successful match
    Extract2 = Cells(Application.Match("*" & x & "*", Columns(3), 0), 6)
Else  ' match was unable to find a result in column 3
    Extract2 = x & " not found in Column 3"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: In my case each cell in the column being searched for can have multiple strings. Setting match_type to 0 only searches for the exact string in the cells. is there an alternative ?

Comment: `Match` can also return larger or smaller values (by changing the third parameter to 1 or -1), is that what you mean ? you can read about the `Match` here :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx

Comment: @jyotirmayapatra see edited code to support searching your string in cells with multiple strings, let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your modified code worked as per my requirements.Thanks a lot for your help!